# How to flush all of the cached contents of Docker memcached?

Tags: docker, memcached

How to flush all of the cached contents of Docker container memcached from command line without restarting memcached?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`docker exec -it $MEMCACHE_CONTAINER_ID bash -c "echo flush_all > /dev/tcp/localhost/11211"`

Comment: When using memcached:alpine. You will get: `exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that you have the memcahed port `11211` exposed. You can flush the cache via either `telnet` or `nc` and sending `flush_all`

```
echo flush_all | nc localhost 11211
OK
```

You can replace localhost, with the machine hostname if you are not executing the command on the same machine where the container is running.

Comment: it won't work since default docker image doesn't have nc

Comment: @caot Execute nc or telnet from the host machine, not inside the container.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the following (also works on alpine docker image):

```
docker exec -it $DOCKER_CONTAINER_ID sh -c "echo flush_all | nc localhost 11211"
```